# Using bash script to pipe breakpoints to debugger prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I am using bash to write a script to make it easier to set breakpoints.

I am trying to see if I can use echo and pipe to send set breakpoints commands to the java debugger jdb.

The command I have strung together successfully sets a breakpoint in jdb, but afterwards it immediately closes the debugger.

I am piping the breakpoint to jdb as follows....

```
(echo -n; sleep 5; echo "stop at MainActivity:77") | jdb -sourcepath app/src/main/java -attach localhost:7777
```

the output is as follows...

```
Initializing jdb ...
> Set breakpoint saf.mobilebeats2.MainActivity:77
> Input stream closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expect`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127354/6631810).

It should be available in repositories of all major distributions. You can write scripts for it, but also one-liners, as you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149367/how-to-get-expect-c-to-work-in-single-line-rather-than-script#3366761).

Here's also its [`man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) if you want to take a look.

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412485/how-to-create-a-loop-statement-within-an-expect-script) an example of looping in Expect.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example in the context of the initial post?

Comment: @ScottF See the first link. It mentions Windows, but also Cygwin, which is a Unix inside Windows. I added one more link to an example of looping in Expect, as you seem to need it.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a sub-shell, you can get your first idea working:

```
( echo "stop at MainActivity:77"; cat -; ) | jdb -sourcepath app/src/main/java -attach localhost:7777
```

This works, because the first STDIN is closed, after the echo command has been processed and secondly the subsequent cat waits for your inputs on the shell.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775964

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564754